# Do you get off the bus at the Röszke border when exiting Hungary for Serbia?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, buses, borders, hungary

When entering Croatia from Serbia at Batrovci, you get off the bus at the Croatian side for passport control, while when exiting Croatia, an offcer boards the bus and collects documents.

When entering Hungary from Serbia at Röszke, you also get off the bus on the Hungarian side.

What about exiting Hungary? Do the Hungarians board the bus or do you have to get off?

Comment: Why is it important?

Comment: @JonathanReez , Maybe for a handicapped passenger that has arranged for help at the end of his trip, but not at the border?

Comment: > What about exiting Hungary? Do the Hungarians board the bus - do you mean the Serbians?

Comment: @chx No, the Hungarians (for exit control). The Serbians always board, at all their crossings

Comment: @JonathanReez I'm travelling with an American who needs his passport stamped, but agents at the land border are frequently lazy about doing it, which we're not going to accept. So it's better if we can be in front of the officer checking the American, otherwise we're gonna have to write a post-it note in Hungarian (in addition to Serbian)

Comment: I [posted](https://www.gyakorikerdesek.hu/utazas__europa__8509152-amikor-magyarorszagrol-szerbiaba-utazik-az-ember-busszal-a-magyar-hatarorok-fel) this to the Hungarian equivalent of Yahoo Answers. If you know Hungarian feel free to follow, if there's an answer I will translate and post.

Comment: @chx I only know bits and pieces of Hungarian, despite being part Hungarian myself. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Hungarian travelers (not first hand experience!) the border guard will board the bus.

Comment: Eh. "Flúgos" doesn't mean stupid closer to "nutter" and it was a brief enough way to explain the rather odd sounding question.